# How to add Array value to JSON Key in Swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, parameters, contacts

**How to add `request.httpBody = getPostData(params: ["contactsList": ["1212121212, "5555555544"]])` in place of
`let parameters = getPostString(params:   ["contactsList":[phNumArray]])`**

below is working code but how to add `phNumArray` in palce of individual of individual numberes to contactsList

**Postman output for API:**

[image] [image]

**working code:** anyone can copy paste to see output

```
import UIKit
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    var phNumArray = ["1111111111", "5555555544"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        callPostApi()
    }

    func getPostString(params: [String: Any]) -> String {
        var data = [String]()
        for (key, value) in params {
            data.append(key + "=\(value)")
        }
        print(data.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "&"))
        return data.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "&")
    }

    func callPostApi() {
        let url = URL(string: "http://itaag-env-1.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/filter/taggedusers/")
        guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("EC3746E9-4DB4-42C7-9D8C-1542B18C2AC", forHTTPHeaderField: "deviceid")
        request.setValue("5fe42fb3b54543a0bab5667cf96526f8", forHTTPHeaderField: "key")
        request.setValue("personal", forHTTPHeaderField: "userType")

        let parameters = getPostString(params: ["contactsList": ["5555555544", "11111111111"]])

        print("json parameter phone numbers \(parameters)")

        request.httpBody = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            // Check for Error
            if let error = error {
                print("Error took place \(error)")
                return
            }
            if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")

                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
                    print("fetching json \(json)")
                    let fetchStatus = json["userName"] as? String
                    print("fetching json userName \(String(describing: fetchStatus))")

                    let user = json["5555555544"] as? [String: Any]
                    let name = user?["userName"] as? String
                    print("first username \(name)")
                } catch {}
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

please help me to solve the issue with `contactsList` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: All this time you were sending the request as `JSON` encoded instead of as `form-data`. I'm adding the code for that below, try it out:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var phNumArray  = ["1111111111", "5555555544"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        callPostApi()
    }

    func getPostData(params: [String:Any]) -> Data? {
        return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
    }

    func callPostApi() {

        let url            = URL(string: "http://itaag-env-1.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/filter/taggedusers/")!
        var request        = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("EC3746E9-4DB4-42C7-9D8C-1542B18C2AC", forHTTPHeaderField: "deviceid")
        request.setValue("5fe42fb3b54543a0bab5667cf96526f8", forHTTPHeaderField: "key")
        request.setValue("personal", forHTTPHeaderField: "userType")

        try? request.setMultipartFormData(["contactsList": "\(phNumArray)"], encoding: .utf8)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, _ in
            if let data = data, let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {

                let user = json["5555555544"] as? [String: Any]
                let name = user?["userName"] as? String
                print("first username \(name)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

extension URLRequest {

    public mutating func setMultipartFormData(_ parameters: [String: String], encoding: String.Encoding) throws {

        let makeRandom = { UInt32.random(in: (.min)...(.max)) }
        let boundary = String(format: "------------------------%08X%08X", makeRandom(), makeRandom())

        let contentType: String = try {
            guard let charset = CFStringConvertEncodingToIANACharSetName(CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding.rawValue)) else {
                throw MultipartFormDataEncodingError.characterSetName
            }
            return "multipart/form-data; charset=\(charset); boundary=\(boundary)"
        }()
        addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        httpBody = try {
            var body = Data()

            for (rawName, rawValue) in parameters {
                if !body.isEmpty {
                    body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
                }

                body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

                guard
                    rawName.canBeConverted(to: encoding),
                    let disposition = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(rawName)\"\r\n".data(using: encoding) else {
                    throw MultipartFormDataEncodingError.name(rawName)
                }
                body.append(disposition)

                body.append("\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

                guard let value = rawValue.data(using: encoding) else {
                    throw MultipartFormDataEncodingError.value(rawValue, name: rawName)
                }

                body.append(value)
            }

            body.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

            return body
        }()
    }
}

public enum MultipartFormDataEncodingError: Error {
    case characterSetName
    case name(String)
    case value(String, name: String)
}
```

Instead of converting to JSON `String` and then converting it to `Data`, use `JSONSerialization`, here's an example:

```swift
func getPostData(params:[String:Any]) -> Data? {
    return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
}
```

And then assign it directly to `URLRequest`'s `httpBody`, like this:

```swift
let arrayOfNumbers = [String]()
arrayOfNumbers.append("5555555544")
arrayOfNumbers.append("11111111111")
request.httpBody = getPostData(params: ["contactsList": arrayOfNumbers])
```

Also, go through the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37), you'll find valuable information there. If don't understand concepts there google more about JSONSerializing and POST request httpBody.

Comment: What type is `phNumArray`? Is it `[String]`? It should be `JSONSerializable`.

Comment: I've updated again to show how to append new numbers to an array.

Comment: Could you make a working code sample in Xcode-Playground and update the code in your question? You should always be asking your question with [minimal-repordusable-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: how to add `phNumArray  to contactsList ` please do something  for this

Comment: error:  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift.__SwiftDeferredNSArray dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000019152e0'`

Comment: have u tried it in ur project...in break point here throwing `for (rawName, rawValue) in parameters {`

Comment: Check how to pass an array as param.